# Pandas dataframe filtering based on group counts

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
item_id       sales_quantity
   1              10             
   1              11 
   1              1 
   1              2
   ...            ...
   10             1
   10             9
   ...            ...
```

I want to filter out all the rows corresponding to an `item_id` which appear less than 100 times. Here is what I tried:

```
from pandas import *
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
def adf(X):

    result = adfuller(X)
    print('ADF Statistic: %f' % result[0])
    print('p-value: %f' % result[1])
    print('Critical Values:')
    for key, value in result[4].items():
        print('\t%s: %.3f' % (key, value))


filtered = df.groupby('item_id_copy')['sales_quantity'].filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 100)
df[df['sales_quantity'].isin(filtered)]
df['sales_quantity'].groupby(df['item_id_copy']).apply(adf)
```

But, when I run the following:
`df['sales_quantity'].groupby(df['item_id_copy']).size()`, I get lots of item_ids with size less than 100. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need remove `['sales_quantity']`:

```
df = df.groupby('item_id_copy').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 100)
```

Or:

```
df = df[df.groupby('item_id_copy')['sales_quantity'].transform('size') > 100]
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(130)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=(10,2)), columns=['item_id_copy','sales_quantity'])
print (df)
   item_id_copy  sales_quantity
0             1               1
1             1               2
2             2               1
3             0               1
4             2               0
5             2               0
6             0               1
7             1               2
8             1               2
9             1               2

df1 = df.groupby('item_id_copy').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 4)
print (df1)
   item_id_copy  sales_quantity
0             1               1
1             1               2
7             1               2
8             1               2
9             1               2

df1 = df[df.groupby('item_id_copy')['sales_quantity'].transform('size') >= 4]
print (df1)
   item_id_copy  sales_quantity
0             1               1
1             1               2
7             1               2
8             1               2
9             1               2
```

EDIT:

For columns after apply some function is possible add `Series` constructor, then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html). Last create new `DataFrame` from dicts in column `Critical Values` and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
np.random.seed(130)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(1000,2)), 
                  columns=['item_id_copy','sales_quantity'])
#print (df)

from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

def adf(X):
    result = adfuller(X)
    return pd.Series(result, index=['ADF Statistic','p-value','a','b','Critical Values','c'])

df1 = df[df.groupby('item_id_copy')['sales_quantity'].transform('size') >= 100]


df2 = df1['sales_quantity'].groupby(df1['item_id_copy']).apply(adf).unstack()
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2['Critical Values'].values.tolist(),
                   index=df2.index, 
                   columns=['1%','5%','10%'])
df2=df2[['ADF Statistic','p-value']].join(df3).reset_index()
print (df2)
   item_id_copy ADF Statistic      p-value        1%        5%       10%
0             1      -12.0739   2.3136e-22 -3.498198 -2.891208 -2.582596
1             2      -4.48264  0.000211343 -3.494850 -2.889758 -2.581822
2             7       -4.2745  0.000491609 -3.491818 -2.888444 -2.581120
3             9      -11.7981  9.47089e-22 -3.486056 -2.885943 -2.579785
```

Comment: I see `item_id` counts both greater than and less than 100 when I run the above mentioned statement (`df['sales_quantity'].groupby(df['item_id_copy']).size()`)

Comment: Hmmm, I am not sure if understand. `Filter` with `groupby` should return all groups by conditions. It not work for you?

Comment: I add some sample, give me some time.

Comment: The second option in your answer works, but with `> 100`. I need to remove the item_ids which occur less than 100 times. Thank you.

Comment: You are rigth, in first solution i have typo - column `sales_quantity` cannot be defined. See edit. And you are right, need `>=100`

Comment: One quick question: I am running a statistical test in the `adf()` function shown in my code. Can you please tell me how I could print the item_id along with the test results? In the current implementation, the test results get printed, but I don't know which item_id a result corresponds to.

Comment: I am not good in statistics, but I try help you. What is desired output? `6` columns?